# Not able to select any of the <options> from <select>using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, drop-down-menu, html-select, webdriverwait

[According to this tutorial](https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/handling-dropdown-in-selenium-webdriver-python/)

I should use this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

with open("sel_path.txt") as path:
    s = path.read()

serv = Service(s)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=serv)
driver.get("https://pynishant.github.io/dropdown-selenium-python-select.html")

lang = driver.find_element(By.ID, "lang1")
select = Select(lang)
select.select_by_value("1")
```

But I get this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
```

I think its not working since the elements show up after the usr clicks the box but I have no idea how to get around that to select the element with Selenium

Ultimately I am trying to target this [box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaJnR.jpg).

I don't know if its because of the old Selenium syntax getting deprecated or not...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you could include the html of the element you want to target I could show that one too.

Answer (score 0):

Cause the dropdown HTML is:

```
<div class="select-items">
   <div>PHP</div>
   <div>Python</div>
   <div>Java</div>
   <div>C#</div>
</div>
```

So you can not use select.

Instead, use:

```
serv = Service(s)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=serv)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://pynishant.github.io/dropdown-selenium-python-select.html")

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.select-selected"))).click()
drop_down_list = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.select-items div")))

desired_option_to_select = 'PHP'
for option in drop_down_list:
    if option.text == desired_option_to_select:
        option.click()
        print('Clicked ', desired_option_to_select, 'option')
        break
    else:
        print('Could not click')
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: //div[@class='select-items']/div[.='PHP']  would work better for an xpath.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan: I am using `css` and I believe it is better than xpath. Agree?

Comment: To target the div tag with the php instead of looping.

Comment: yes, that would be another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You were close enough. However a few points:

### Test Lang section

- It's not a *SELECT* tag so you can't use `Select()`

### Solution

To select ***PHP*** from the dropdown you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

Code Block:

```
driver.get("https://pynishant.github.io/dropdown-selenium-python-select.html")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='select-selected']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='select-items']/div[text()='PHP']"))).click()
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: individual_select]

---

### Select your lang section

- The *SELECT* tag have the *`id`* attribute as **lang** but not **lang1**. So the effective line of code will be:

  ```
  lang = driver.find_element(By.ID, "lang")
  ```
- There is no `option` with *value* as **1** but ***php***, ***c#***, ***python*** and ***java***

### Solution

You can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

Code Block:

```
driver.get("https://pynishant.github.io/dropdown-selenium-python-select.html")
Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='lang']")))).select_by_value("php")
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: option_select]